# Android Firebase An internal error has occurred. [ Broken pipe ]

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

[image: An internal error has occurred.]

Why am I getting this error?

```
   public void sigIn(LoginUserModel loginUserModel, Activity activity,Class<?> targetClass) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginUserModel.getUserEmail(), loginUserModel.getUserPassword())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, targetClass.getClass());
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Login Fail", error);
                    }
                });
    }
```

```
  public void userLoginButton(View view) {
        userEmailTxt = userName.getText().toString();
        userPasswordTxt = userPassword.getText().toString();

        loginUserModel = new LoginUserModel(userEmailTxt, userPasswordTxt);
        if (LoginUserInputValidator(loginUserModel, context)) {
            loginManager.sigIn(loginUserModel, LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        }
    }
```

My username and password information is correct, but I am getting this error, and I can't figure out the reason.

[image: Firebase web site]

Comment: What is the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).